# Confidence Interval of Sample Means using R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, sampling

My dataframe contains sampling means of 500 samples of size 100 each. Below is the snapshot. I need to calculate the confidence interval at 90/95/99 for mean.

```
head(Means_df)
  Means
1 14997
2 11655
3 12471
4 12527
5 13810
6 13099
```

I am  using the below code but only getting the confidence interval for one row only. Can anyone help me with the code?

```
tint <- matrix(NA, nrow = dim(Means_df)[2], ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:dim(Means_df)[2]) {
  temp <- t.test(Means_df[, i], conf.level = 0.9)
  tint[i, ] <- temp$conf.int
}
colnames(tint) <- c("lcl", "ucl")
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a confidence interval for each row? And for each row you only have a single value (which is I'm assuming the mean of some other data)?

Answer (score 1):

`Means_df` is a data frame with 500 rows and 1 column. Therefore

```
dim(Means_df)[2]
```

will give the value `1`.

Which is why you only get one value.

Solve the problem by using `dim(Means_df)[1]` or even better `nrow(Means_df)` instead of `dim(Means_df)[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

For any single mean, e. g. 14997, you can not compute a 95%-CI without knowing the variance or the standard deviation of the data, the mean was computed from. If you have access to the standard deviation of each sample, you can than compute the standard error of the mean and with that, easily the 95%-CI. Apparently, you lack the Information needed for the task.